# Dualizable presheaves with respect to Day convolution

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, duality, convolution

This question was posted on MSE and got very little attention, so I'm also posting it here.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a closed symmetric monoidal category and let $PSh(\mathcal{C}):=Fun(\mathcal{C}^{op}, \mathbf{Set})$ be its category of presheaves regarded as a closed symmetric monoidal category via Day convolution of presheaves.

Is there a nice description of the dualizable objects of $PSh(\mathcal{C})$
in terms of the dualizable objects of $\mathcal{C}$? For example, could it be that the dualizable presheaves $PSh(\mathcal{C})_{fd}$ consists of objects given as filtered (co)limits of dualizable objects in $\mathcal{C}$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Lemma:** In a closed symmetric monoidal category where the unit object $1$ is [tiny](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tiny+object) (meaning $\text{Hom}(1, -)$ preserves colimits), every dualizable object is tiny.

*Proof.* If $x$ is dualizable, then $\text{Hom}(x, -) \cong \text{Hom}(1, x^{\ast} \otimes (-))$. Since the monoidal structure is assumed to be closed, $x^{\ast} \otimes (-)$ preserves colimits, and by assumption so does $\text{Hom}(1, -)$. $\Box$

The unit object in $\text{Psh}(C)$ is the presheaf represented by the unit object; since colimits in presheaf categories are computed pointwise, every representable presheaf is tiny, so the lemma applies and we conclude that every dualizable object in $\text{Psh}(C)$ is tiny. But it's [standard](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/05/07/tiny-objects/) that the tiny objects in $\text{Psh}(C)$ are precisely the retracts of the representable presheaves. Among these, the dualizable objects include the presheaves represented by dualizable objects in $C$, as well as (I think?) their retracts. I don't know if it's possible for a nontrivial retract of a presheaf represented by a non-dualizable object to be dualizable.

Comment: There are plenty of dualizable retracts of non-dualizable objects (finite dimensional subvector spaces of infinite-dimensional ones). However, the idempotent completion of $C$ has a natural monoidal structure, and your argument shows that the dualizable objects of  $Ph(C)$ are those of the idempotent completion of $C$. And one cannot do better: it is possible that C has no non-trivial dualizable objects while its idempotent completion has many (e.g. C=infinite dimensional vector spaces with countable basis).